# XML parsing is not working as expected in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, xml-parsing

I am new to iPhone programming, and this is the first time parsing XML file. I have added  the url and also hardcoded the XML file into the string, however I am not getting the correct response from the server.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *post = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\"encoding=\"UTF-8\"?<request><call>GetNewChapters</call><udid>1000000000000000000000000000000000000000</udid><book_id>1</book_id><updatetoken>B20100125054802</updatetoken></request>";

NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.paisible.com/babelle_api"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];    
[request setHTTPBody:postData];



NSString *myStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"String Value :%@",myStr);


NSLog(@"theRequest: %@", request);
NSURL *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
if(theConnection)
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

Where as webdata is NSMutable data. Please let me know what errors I have made in my parsing code.

Comment: Whoosa! calm down we will try get this fixed. No need to scream.

Comment: Oops! Your caps lock key appears to be broken.

Comment: Please clarify your last two sentences - preferably without full caps.

Comment: i can also provide the xml structure <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request>
<call>GetNewChapters</call>
<udid>1000000000000000000000000000000000000000</udid>
<book_id>1</book_id>
<updatetoken>B20100125054802</updatetoken>
</request> plz let me know whats wrong with the code and also check for the url

Comment: What is the response you are getting? I think you havent pasted/written the delegate methods for getting the response.

Comment: no praveen i have written all the three delegate method for NSXML however the response which i am getting from the server is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><call></call><return_code>ERROR</return_code><message>Empty Request</message><actioncode>EXIT</actioncode></response>

Comment: when the NSURL connection Did finish loading is called then  NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes] length:[webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
 NSLog(@"theXML: %@", theXML);
call this lines to check the response from the server

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

```
NSURL *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

with the following:

```
NSURLResponse *resp;
NSError *error;
NSMutableData *webData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&resp error:&error];
```

Than, check what "webData" contains.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but Mike i have implemented what you have said,however it didn't work, showing the same response as previous and also one warning (Incompatible Ojective-C types assigning struct NSDATA expected struct NSMutableData) also MIKE please let me know wheather is there any problem with the url.

Comment: try to allocate the request like this: NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

Comment: i have find the solution, and its working and getting response from the server when we start to read xml i have written @"xml = and the rest of the string,thanks for the information and help.

Comment: Hello @kashif Please share your solution as an Answer so it may help to other also, i have also same problem. so please share.